# How can I prevent repetition in my javascript funtion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following ways to prevent special characters to be typed into input boxes with ids A, B and C with jQuery and is working as expected. This is happening on ***(document).ready***.

```
$("[id$='A']").keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
        return true;
    }                 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});    
$("[id$='B']").keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
        return true;
    }                 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}); 
$("[id$='C']").keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
        return true;
    }                 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a common method instead of writing the function over again. Here's what I tried...

```
function blockSpecialChar(passId){
    var tempId = $("[id$ ='passId']");
                 tempId.keypress(function (e) {
                    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
                    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
                    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
                        return true;
                    }                 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });   

}
```

and calling it by:

```
 blockSpecialChar(A);
```

Let me know where am I going wrong. Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your `html`

Comment: Please just use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute and let them know when it's not acceptable input with css `:invalid`. This don't stop me from pasting in special character

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a separate function:

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
        return true;
    }                 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

$("[id$='A'], [id$='B'], [id$='C']").keypress(blockSpecialChar);
```

Comment: Thanks @this-lau. It worked. Boy, I was far from close :D

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the `id` of element but you are using it as `string`

```
function blockSpecialChar(passId){
    var tempId = $("[id$ ='"+passId+"']");
    tempId.keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str) || (/^(8|9|13|27)$/.test("" + e.keyCode))) {                    
        return true;
     }                 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
   });   

}
```